# Convert Complex Pivot SQL Query to Laravel Eloquent Relation

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, relationship, query-builder

I have a question regarding the extract of a schema you see below:

[image: Example SQL Schema]

As you see there are `tasks` that are connected with `files` through a pivot table `task_files`.
The pivot table has an enum column `io` with possible values `input` and `output`.

I would like to create an eager-loadable Laravel Eloquent relation that returns dependent tasks of a task. I guess the existing relation types are not sufficient for such a kind of query. At least I couldn't find out how and therefore would be glad for any help.

I have a working SQL raw query that basically does what it should use subqueries. Please note that there are some constraints missing (e.g. soft delete) that would be needed for the real application.

```sql
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    wecreateyour.tasks
WHERE
    id IN (SELECT 
            inputs.task_id
        FROM
            wecreateyour.task_files AS inputs
        WHERE
            inputs.io = 'input'
                AND inputs.file_id IN (SELECT 
                    outputs.file_id
                FROM
                    wecreateyour.task_files AS outputs
                WHERE
                    outputs.io = 'output'
                        AND outputs.file_id = inputs.file_id
                        AND outputs.task_id IN (?)));
```

Comment: It sounds like you need to build the relationship between tasks, inputs, and outputs. Do you currently have attempts to do this in place which are not working? Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: Well no, there is no code worth showing. For sure i tinkered around, but that was all rubbish. Please note that there are no separate inputs and inputs tables. These are only aliases of the subqueries. And this is actually the problem. I need a relation based on a subquery and not a foreign key column.